# JavaScript How to obtain get var from script file

Tags: javascript, php

Maybe is too basic but i could not do it, i have a `php` file and inside of it i call a `js` file. Inside that `js` i need to obtain a get var from the `php` file.

I have the following

PHP File:

```
<script language="javascript" src="scripts/scripts.js?tiempo=<?php echo $marcaTiempo; ?>"></script>
```

and in the `scripts.js` i need to get the var tiempo.

How can i achieve it?

Thanks

Comment: It is not that, i need to read the var inside the scripts.js, not the php, i don't know how to get it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the value from URL Parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter)

Comment: Are you trying to get something from the URL `"scripts/scripts.js?tiempo...`" or are you trying to get something from the resulting script file?  Your question is not clear on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**

Make the server handle the js file as a php file, and do something like:

```
<?php
$tiempo = filter_input(INPUT_GET,"tiempo",FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
?>
var tiempo = <?php echo $tiempo; ?>;
```

Obviously not great for caching.

**Option 2**

Declare the parameter globally:

```
<script>
 var tiempo=<?php echo $marcaTiempo; ?>
</script>
<script src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
```

and in scripts.js:

```
var tiempo = window.tiempo;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this in the past by doing the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var tiempo = <?php echo $marcaTiempo; ?>;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
```

Then the variable is accessible from your script.